# I have vibration data(g) in x and y direction for a Ball Bearing in 2 columns.Is there a way to find Manhattan distance just with this data & time?

Tags: matlab, distance

I have frequency data in x and y direction for a Ball Bearing. And the Absolute time ofcourse in Another column. Is there a way to find Manhattan distance just with Frequecy and Absolute time.. so, can anyone just guide me?

```
For example the given file is like below

     3.54393190998923540E+9 -6.80819749832153320E-2 -1.33635997772216800E-2 
     3.54393190998923540E+9 -6.80819749832153320E-2 -1.33635997772216800E-2
     3.54393190998923540E+9 -6.80819749832153320E-2 -1.33635997772216800E-2
     3.54393190998923540E+9 -6.80819749832153320E-2 -1.33635997772216800E-2
```

Here, first column is Time, And 2nd and 3rd columns are frequency data in x and y. How do we find manhattan distance here?

Comment: Why not use a cell/struct or multi-dimensional matrix for that? On a side note, which language are you using, bash of MATLAB?

Comment: i need to do it in matlab actually. @Adrian

Comment: The why is it tagged bash and shell? The first answer you received already uses something that is not-MATLAB. Please remove any irrelevant tags.

Comment: Echoing @Adriaan, unless you have some very specific use case, assigning 3 million variables to your workspace will almost certainly crash MATLAB. At the very least it will severely affect performance. MATLAB has many ways to organize sets of data like this besides breaking it up into individual pieces. If you can provide more information on your use case (are you doing the same operation on each line? are you doing a different operation on every third line? Are you doing a different operation on each line?) We can give you a better answer to your question.

Comment: If you do end up surprising us, and indeed can show that you actually need 3 million uniquely named variables in your workspace, there are ways to make MATLAB do it.

Comment: After accepting the answer to your question, you changed the question. Better to open up a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read all of the data in at once using [dlmread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-numeric-data-from-a-text-file.html) and then access each of the columns individually:

```
M = dlmread('datafile.txt');
```

`dlmread` will figure out the delimiter and give you the correct number of columns in `M`:

```
M =

   3.5439e+09  -6.8082e-02  -1.3364e-02
   3.5439e+09  -6.8082e-02  -1.3364e-02
   3.5439e+09  -6.8082e-02  -1.3364e-02
   3.5439e+09  -6.8082e-02  -1.3364e-02
```

Now you can access column 2, for example, like so:

```
>> M(:,2)
ans =

  -0.068082
  -0.068082
  -0.068082
  -0.068082
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
perl -i -pe 's/ /,/g;s/^/a$.=/' junk.txt
```

Comment: The OP was rather lavish with random tags and apparently needs to do this in MATLAB. Apologies for causing that.